# Filling a column from a cell

Tags: worksheet-function, android

If I have a cell containing a date I cannot fill it down because it will add one day to the date.

How can I have the same date for all of the cells?

E.g. A2 10-Sep goes to A3 11-Sep A4 12-Sep etc.

Comment: Select cell, Ctrl-C, then select destination range, Ctrl-V. Alternative - fill 2 cells, select both, fill them down.

Comment: @Akina I am on Excel for Android.

Comment: Both variants are impossible or do not give the result you need?

Comment: @Akina what both variants? I cannot perform Ctrl-C on a phone. I am missing a Ctrl button.

Comment: You cannot select 2-cells range? *what both variants?* Main (first) and alternative (second).

Comment: @JossieCalderon, the confusion may be from the fact that you're on Android, which is off-topic here (hover on the tag).  I've voted to migrate it to the Android site for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel tries guessing the pattern when auto-filling.

When you present only one data point (a single day), it will assume you want the next field to be the value subsequent to that data point.

If you present Excel with TWO data points (two adjacent cells filled in with the same date) it will know what you want more clearly.

So, fill in two cells with the same date, select BOTH of them, then drag the auto-fill extender box to the rest of the cells you wish to fill, and Excel will fill these with the same value, exactly as you desire.